# Generate MD5sum for all files in a directory, and then write (filename).md5 for each file containing that file's MD5SUM

Tags: bash, hashsum

I have a directory full of files. Each file will be copied to a specific type of destination host.

I want to calculate an MD5 sum for each file in the directory, and store that md5 sum in a file that matches the name of the file that generated the sum, but with .md5 appended.

So, for instance, if I have a directory with:

```
a.bin
b.bin
c.bin
```

The final result should be:

```
a.bin
a.bin.md5     # a.bin's calculated checksum
b.bin
b.bin.md5     # b.bin's calculated checksum
c.bin
c.bin.md5     # c.bin's calculated checksum
```

I have attempted this with find exec, and with xargs.

With find, I tried this command:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + > {}.md5
```

Using xargs, I tried this command:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I {} md5sum {} > {}.md5
```

In either case, I end up with a file called {}.txt, which isn't really what I am looking for.

Could anyone point out how to tweak these to generate the md5 files I am looking to generate?

Comment: Dumping all the output to a single file will let you use `md5sum -c` later to verify all files at once.

Comment: The problem is we won't be copying all files to the destinations. Only one file will be copied. So, we'd end up with a monolithic file listing files that mostly aren't present on the destination hosts. Using the example above, some hosts get a.bin, some get b.bin. The a.bin hosts don't need md5sum info for b.bin and c.bin. I hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: Properly escaped xargs call `find . -type f | xargs -I {} sh -c 'md5sum '{}' > '{}'.md5'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/files &&
for file in *; do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        md5sum -- "$file" > "${file}.md5"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Redirection is an operator of the shell.

In:

```
find some args  > {}.md5
```

`find` is run with some args and its stdout redirected to `{}.md5`.

Here, you'd need `find` to start a shell to perform one redirection for each file:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    md5sum "$file" > "$file.md5"
  done' sh {} +
```

If you want to avoid the directory component in the `.md5` part, you can either use the `-execdir` alternatives supported by many `find` implementations (though with some you'll still get a `./` directory component, and with some, that will still run one shell per file even with `{} +`:

```
find . -type f -execdir sh -c '
  for file do
    md5sum "$file" > "$file.md5"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or you can do it as:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    (cd "${file%/*" && exec md5sum -- "${file##*/}") > "$file.md5"
  done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there are side effects to piping into a while loop, but I like the simplicilty, readability and extensibilty of this solution

```
find . -type f ! -name \*.md5 |\
  while read a; do md5sum $a > $a.md5; done
```

To use this scipplet to check sums simply:

```
find . -type f ! -name \*.md5 |\
  while read a; do echo $a; md5sum -c $a.md5; done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -name '*.iso' -type f -exec sh -c "ls -lh {}; pv {} | md5sum > {}.md5" \;
```

optional

```
ls -lh {};
```

to show processing file, and

```
pv {}
```

to show progressbar on big (slow) iso file in my case

Comment: Looks OK, but you're restricting it to .iso files.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /path/to/files && ls -1| xargs md5sum |  xargs -l bash -c 'echo $0"  "$1 > $1.md5'
```

first xargs generate , second xargs picks up and save  to .md5

If you need filter file patter, you can replace ls with find or add grep afterwards.

Comment: Parses output of `ls` and uses unquoted variable expansions.

Comment: Can you explain your comments? you can replace ls with find or any other command.

Comment: Assume spaces in any of the names in the `files` directory, for example. Also consider what would happen if one of the names is a directory.

Comment: @MingJia Parsing output of `ls` is considered generally bad practice (see [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) ). Even if there aren't any difficult filenames, that doesn't mean one shouldn't anticipate them.  Second big problem is the `$0` and `$1` should be double-quoted. Because of "word splitting", if you have file with spaces or tabs in filename, ` > $1`  will have `ambiguous redirect` error. Try `var="with space.txt"; echo "hi" > $var` and then `var="with space.txt"; echo "hi" > "$var"`

Comment: @MingJia Don't get discouraged, you'll learn to pick up on these things if you stick around on the site, with time of course. Welcome, to the site and consider re-working your answer.

Comment: Yeah, what he said. Sorry for being a bit short in my comments above. Your answer is welcomed, definitely, and I'm known to sometimes be a bit strict in my code reviews...